# Pass list of values on query parameter

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hql

```
String hql = "select * from myTable where isActive IN (:isActive)";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setString("school","");
        query.setString("isActive", "Y");//working
        query.setString("isActive", "N");//working
        query.setString("isActive", "Y","N"); // not working
        query.setString("isActive", "'Y','N'"); // not working
        return query.list();
```

I have no idea if the code below should work, I was wondering if i can pass list of values to my search string parameter so there's no need for me to create to queries ; one for select all data regardless of status and another to select only active data.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Query.setParameterList()` to pass in a `List` as a parameter:

```
String hql = "select * from myTable where isActive IN (:isActive)";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List<String> isActiveList = new ArrayList<>();
isActiveList.add("Y");
isActiveList.add("N");
query.setParameterList("isActive", isActiveList);
return query.list();
```